# Screenshot of an Area Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, app-shortcuts, screenshot

I am able to use keyboard shortcuts to take a screenshot of my entire screen (which automatically saves in the Pictures folder - side question how do I change where it saves?).
When I try to use the keyboard shortcut to take a screenshot of an area as per the other options in the System Settings-->Keyboard-->Shortcuts-->Screenshots nothing happens.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Is the a way to run the actual 'Take a screenshot' application using shortcuts?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Iri[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Terminal and with the command `screenshot-tool --help` you can see all the available options.

Then you can define your personal Keyboard-Shortcut in *Switchboard > Keyboard > Custom ...*

I do not know how i can set a specified destination but for me, with the following shortcuts, screenshot-tool saves automatically in *~/Pictures/Screenshots*

[image: Picture is from german language 'Benutzerdefiniert = Custom']